# Dealing with non-ascii string as array and � character

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to write function to do the `number_format()` job for the non-ascii numbers , specifically perso-arabic numbers.

First i have to exchange the numbers which leaves me with a string of non-ascii characters:

```
$n = 133;
$n = exchange($n);
echo $n ;
//result : ١٣٣
```

The problem is when I add the commas to the number or rather string, my final result comes with some � characters.

Here is the function that I use to add the commas:

```
    static public function addcomma($number)
       {

    $i = strlen($number)-1;
    $c = 0 ;

    for($i ; $i >= 0 ; $i--){
    $c++;

    if($c == 1 ) 
    $y =mb_substr($number, $i, 1);
    else 
    $y .= mb_substr($number, $i, 1);



    if($c%3 == 0 && $i != 0 )
    $y .=',';
    }
    $y = strrev($y);
    return $y;

    }
```

And this is the result for `$n = ١٣٣`:

٣,٣�,�١

Comment: What place do you need to put the comma? And what encoding is that string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your characters (likely all) are stored on more than one byte, unline regular ASCII strings. So you have to use [multibyte string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) to manipulate the strings. You can't use  `strlen`, `substr` and `strrev` (or any other regular string function), and you can't just treat the string as an array. So, you have to change some sections of your code, like this:

```
$i = mb_strlen($number)-1;
// (...)
$y = mb_substr($number, $i, 1);
```

There is no multibyte equivalent for `strrev`, so you can try this (suggested on a [comment](http://co.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php#107664) at the `strrev` manual page):

```
// strrev won't work
// $y = strrev($y); 
$y = join("", array_reverse(preg_split("//u", $y)));
```

The above will split the string into an array, respecting the multibyte boundaries (note the `u` at the end of the regex), reverse that array, and then join it back to a string.

Comment: sorry i was wrong it's not just breaking the original string but also  when i add the commas , those characters appear on the result too , the string comes out fine if i dont add the commas , any thought on that ?

Comment: @max, see my updated answer. You can't use regular string functions anywhere when dealing with those multibyte strings.

Comment: add the encoding ('UTF-8') to the code and it will work as expected. If you check $i from mb_strlen($number)-1, you'll see that it returns 5 instead of 2. So used mb_strlen($number,'UTF-8') to get the correct length and put encoding on every mb function because php may guess wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your arabic string (ie, whatever you get from `exchange()`) is very likely encoded in UTF-8, or basically some non 8-bit format.  As soon as you begin twiddling with the string as an array (which PHP assumes is 8-bit), you break the UTF-8 string and it comes out with those funny question marks when it's printed to the screen (which by the way, ensure your document encoding type is set to UTF-8 as well).

Depending on the version of PHP, you'll need to use mb_string functions to fiddle with multi-byte strings, which is what you have.

Comment: sorry i was wrong it's not just breaking the original string but also  when i add the commas , those characters appear on the result too , the string comes out fine if i dont add the commas , any thought on that ?

Comment: Again, it's because UTF-8 is not just an 8-bit character string.  Depending on the actual bits, a UTF-8 character can either be 8-bits or 16-bits (or more, I believe?).  The mix of a UTF-8 character and then a simple 8-bit character and a display encoding of UTF-8 could cause the browser to mis-print your commas thinking it's part of a UTF-8 character.

Comment: thanx i've tried to force the commas to utf-8 with utf8_encode before adding them to the string but it didn't work , i think i have to use a array to hold each character and then convert it to string at the end

Comment: The problem is not encoding commas or anything - you cannot access the string as an array.  You **must** use the mb_string functions, and only those functions for manipulating the string.